# cordova plugin location-accuracy not showing request

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am using the [Location Accuracy Plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) in combination with Ionic (testing in Android).

When calling

```
this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
.then(() => resolve("Request successful"),
 error => {
   console.error("Error requesting location : "+error.message);
});
```

I get no feedback. Neither does the popup - which is supposed to appear - show up, nor is there any message in the console. When I try to call the request again, it tells me that there is already a request in progress. So the problem is, that I can just not see the request on the screen, but it somehow seems so happen in the backend and get stuck somewhere.

The requestLocationAuthorization() returns "Granted" and canRequest() returns true on the first call but false later on. Everything works as intended here too.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

```
public checkHomeLocationAccuracy() {

    this.splashScreen.hide();
    this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {
        console.log("canRequest" + canRequest);
        if (!canRequest) {
            this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
                () => this.getHomeSetRoot(),
                error => this.platform.exitApp(),
            );
        } else {
            this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
                () => this.getHomeSetRoot(),
                error => this.platform.exitApp(),
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain how this code solves the problem.